# Create a Dictionary of Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> to store in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure

I have a DynamicTableEntity already created for my azure table storage

```
var tableRecords= new DynamicTableEntity( partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props );

List<string> Mycolumns = {a, b,c,d} ;
IEnumerable<object> Myvalues = {r,t,y,i};
```

now I have another set of properties to be added, lets say now I have a list of columns which is of `*List<string>*` type and List of values in *`IEnumerable<object>`* type .

My existing table record is generated like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV( Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols )
    {
        using( TextReader reader = new StreamReader( source, Encoding.UTF8 ) )
        {
            var cache = new TypeConverterCache();
            cache.AddConverter<float>( new CSVSingleConverter() );
            cache.AddConverter<double>( new CSVDoubleConverter() );
            var csv = new CsvReader( reader,
                new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration( global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
                {
                    Delimiter = ",",
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    CultureInfo = global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    TypeConverterCache = cache
                } );
            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();
            var map = (
                    from col in cols
                    from src in col.Sources()
                    let index = csv.GetFieldIndex( src, isTryGet: true )
                    where index != -1
                    select new { col.Name, Index = index, Type = col.DataType }).ToList();

            while( csv.Read() )
            {
                yield return map.ToDictionary(
                    col => col.Name,
                    col => EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject( csv.GetField( col.Type, col.Index ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

     
    

    public async Task WriteToTable( Stream lines, DataClass dataclass,
       Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<(string, string)>> genKeys,
       Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<List<string>>> generateColumns, List<string> columnsList,
       bool upsert )
    {
        const int BatchSize = 100;
        if( HasPartitionAndRowKey( dataclass.TableSchema.Fields ) )
        {
            genKeys = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props ) => Task.FromResult( (props["PartitionKey"].StringValue, props["RowKey"].ToString()) );

        }

        var tableRecords = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
    .Select( async props =>
    {
        var (partitionKey, rowKey) = await genKeys( props );
        return new DynamicTableEntity( partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props );
    } )
    .ToList();           
        
        await BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( BatchSize, tableRecords, upsert );

    }
```

How do I add this in the existing tableRecords?

Comment: Mycolumss are properties name; and Myvalues are entities 's properties?

Comment: yes thats right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before initializing tableRecords, you add them into props:

```
    var tableRecords = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
.Select( async props =>
{   
    var (partitionKey, rowKey) = await genKeys( rops );
    return new DynamicTableEntity( partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props );
} )
.ToList();   
        var arr = Myvalues.toArray();
        var newprops = new dictionary<string, EntityProperty>();        
        for(int i = 0; i< Mycolums.count;i++)
        {
          newprops.Add(Mycolums[i], arr[i]);
        }
//i dont know if you partitionkey /row keys are include in your props so you fill them
 tableRecords.Add(new DynamicTableEntity( partition_Key, row_Key, string.Empty, newprops ));

await BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( BatchSize, tableRecords, upsert );
```

so in linq, you could use :

```
        var newprops = Mycolumns.Zip(Myvalues, (k, v) => new { k, v })
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

instead of:

```
        var arr = Myvalues.toArray();
        var newprops = new dictionary<string, EntityProperty>();        
        for(int i = 0; i< Mycolums.count;i++)
        {
          newprops.Add(Mycolums[i], arr[i]);
        }
```

Comment: My props are basically generated in a Linq method. How do I deal with that. See the Question I have edited with existing tableRecords.

Comment: yes I am getting that and I even have props .. but now a new set of properties need to be added

Comment: yes it remains same. Props and rows are generated by function delegate which has own set of operation which depends on the file read.for eg: I am taking FileName as PartitionKey

Comment: added my existing methods as how I am reading and inserting to tables. now new set of fields/values needs to be added in the table records along with the existing one. these new ones are not there in the CSV file.

Comment: its more complex, you want to add new entities  to all items of tablerecords?

Comment: i want to add new items in the tableRecords

Comment: tableRecords is of List<Task<DynamicTableEntity>> type, if I can create another DynamicTableEntity with list of Values and add in tableRecords, I think that should do

Comment: but here old props has been replaced with newprops, i have to keep the old props as well

Comment: your new props have  new partition key and row key? for each item of list?

Comment: no... they will be appended with the existing props. so each row will have partitionkey,rowkey,value of old columns from props,value of new columns from new props

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229243/discussion-between-frenchy-and-zzzsharepoint).